# How to pass multiple locators in Selenium webdriver to fetch an element on a page

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Hi can anyone pls solve this. When i write a code to automate sometimes the elements are not identified and sometimes its not found even they are present, means even if the id is present it says element not found error. So I a trying to create a method where i would pass all the dom objects i find like Ex :

```
public static void Click(WebDriver driver, String name,Sting linktext,Sting id,Sting Xpath,String css)

{
driver.findElement(new ByAll(By.name(name),
By.linkText(linktext),
By.id(id),
By.xpath(xpath),
By.cssSelector(css))).click();
 }
```

And  i would pass what ever value i find in source page like sometimes it will have oly id or it ll have oly link text Ex:(when i import this method in other class)

```
Click(Webdriver driver, "username",null,"","//[fas].user");
```

is this the correct way to pass the arguments. can i pass like null and "" (blank). Pls help this would become a one simple effective framework for me.

Comment: Why would you need this?

Answer (score 0):

```
   you can use this 2 methods 

         public static WebElement findElement(WebDriver driver, By selector, long timeOutInSeconds) {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(selector));

            return findElement(driver, selector);
          }

         public static WebElement findElementSafe(WebDriver driver, By selector, long timeOutInSeconds) {
            try {
              return findElement(driver, selector, timeOutInSeconds);
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
              return null;
            }
          }

      public static void waitForElementToAppear(WebDriver driver, By selector, long timeOutInSeconds, String timeOutMessage) {
        try {
          WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);
          wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(selector));
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
          throw new IllegalStateException(timeOutMessage);
        }
      }


----------------
  public static void click(WebDriver driver , By ... selector ){
    for (By byPath : selector) {
      WebElement element = findElementSafe(driver, byPath, 1);
      if(element != null){
        element.click();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: ok Thanks will try this and is it possible to sen the arguments like this =  Click(Webdriver driver, "username",null,"","//[fas].user");  for my above method ??

Comment: i am not getting how to pass the xpath or id value or to the selector in your method @ran

Comment: you can override this method you can pass parameter " By" it can be whatever you want , i would not use multiply path as a best practice

Comment: i add one more method that you can use

Comment: ran sry i am not getting how to pass the parameter here, can u pls past an example with sm dummy parameters in ur method , i am pretty new to webdriver... or u can mail me at rraki68@gmail.com   :)

Comment: i have added an example

Comment: if you need more then one path you are doing something wrong :(

Comment: find elementsafe shows me error, it say the findelement method is undefined do i need to import any specific jar ??
below are the current jar i am using at present